# Module not found in project (Python)

Tags: python, module, pytest

I'm a beginner and I'm not understanding something in the project folder structure.

I have this project:

```
.
└── convertersProject/
    ├── conftest.py -----------------> best practice if you're not using src structure
    ├── converters  -----------------> module I'm trying to import/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── binconverter.py
    │   └── importester1.py  --------> import binconverter OR from converters import */
    │       └── submodule/
    │           ├── __init__.py -----> not needed if I don't want to use it as package
    │           └── importester2.py -> from converter import binconverter 
    ├── outsidemodule  /
    │   ├── importester3.py
    │   └── __init__.py 
    └── test /
        └── test_converters.py
```

I'm receiving always `ModuleNotErrorFound` when trying to execute `importester1/2/3.py` directly from project folder. I'm using a virtual enviroment, setting up with `python -m venv 'name'` from a pyenv python 3.8.5 set with `pyenv shell 3.8.5`

What I think I'm understanding:

- I have to use absolute paths as `from converters.binconverter import bin2dec` being bin2dec fucntion in binconverter. If I'd want to use relative, I should be inside the folder tree as trying to execute `importertest2.py`, because `submodule` is inside `converters`. So, I coudn't use relatives for `outsidemodule`
- PYTHONPATH is the current folder you're executing, so if I executing from project folder as `python converters/submodule/importester2.py`, I don't have to append any value to the PYTHONPATH of the virtual enviroment (indeed, I've read  it's not a good practice)
- `__init__.py` allows you to use module without appending values to PYTHONPATH virtualenv, so I could `import` the `converter` module into `outsidemodule` using absolute paths.
- `tests` are working using this logic. In fact if I change something the VSCode debugger detect `import` problems.

What the hell am I missing?

Comment: add the init file to all the folders. even the root one

Comment: I've already done it and it doesn't work. In fact it is currently  in my project folder.

Comment: Is that weird ?? Please help. I've been for two days with that problem and the only way I'm able to load project modules is installing them via setup.py.

Comment: Ok, PYTHONPATH is not an existing variable you have to created with export temporarily in your console or configure it properly in your IDE. I'm using VS Code that doesn't do this automatically. It is essential for debugging. Thanks anyway!